# What is the javascript if statement I could use to only display something AFTER a new option is chosen?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, document.write

I have a select list:

```
Choose a Story:</br>
<select name="Book" id="book">
<option value="empty" selected disabled></option>
<option value="Book1">Book1</option>
<option value="Book2">Book2</option>
<option value="Book3">Book3</option>
<option value="Book4">Book4</option>
</select><br><br>
```

I got the script to work to display the chosen item onchange below the options thanks to some assistance from other stackoverflow users. But it only states what option is chosen instead of getting it to say "You chose *_*." after something other than the blank option is chosen.

```
<script>
 $('#book').on('change', function() {
        $('#result_element').text(this.value);
    });
</script>

<script>
if ((document.getElementsByTagName("book")this.value) != empty)
{
document.write("You chose ")
}
</script>
<span id="result_element"></span>
```

Basically, I want it to show the "You chose *_*_." after they select something.

Comment: not a php problem, do it with javascript

Comment: roger that. will make changes and report back with results. @Populus

Comment: `if( user.canFormulateBasicCode) answerQuestion(); else postCondescendingComment();`

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("book")this.value` is probably where your code is breaking.

Comment: thanks for nothing niet but I'm still learning and starting from nothing fellas. Thank you though for pointing me to that error @bmceldowney, I will look into that and read up on those.

Comment: `$('#result_element').text('You chose: ' + this.value);` reference: [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Also, I'd suggest not using your second `script`, it seems full of problems (that I, sadly, don't have time to detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) You will need to do it in the event handler. Otherwise the code is executed when the page is loaded (and not again), instead of after the user has chosen an option
b) [Do not use `document.write`!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

```
<script>
 $('#book').on('change', function() {
     var output = "";
     if (this.value != "empty") {
         output = "You chose " + this.value;
     }
     $('#result_element').text(output);
 });
</script>
<span id="result_element"></span>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @bergi! I was learning different things and got directed in the wrong way and I see now that I was mixing several things and digging myself deeper. Thank you again for the assistance and I will continue to learn! I'd upvote that, but I don't have the privileges yet.